# how git clone locally (to my machine) using Dockerfile? ( git ) , (docker)

Tags: docker

I am trying to git clone repo to my **machine(locally)** while running dockerfile.

But, it is cloning in to container.

I need to be cloned to my local machine, ple correct me if my **Dockerfile** is wrong.

***Here is my Docker file***

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN git clone https://github.com/testgithub-trial/docktest.git
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how git clone locally (to my machine) using Dockerfile?

It is not possible to do anything to your machine from Dockerfile.

> I need to be cloned to my local machine

So do not use a Dockerfile. You can do from a docker container by bind-mounting a directory, but not from `docker build`.